# Wordpress: Open edit attachment modal with wp.media

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm doing a custom interface for media upload in WordPress admin area. So far i used wp.media to open the upload modal window and manage to upload and save images using this code

```
var frame = new wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select({
    .....
    ....
});
```

Now i,m trying to edit the attachments and after looking in media-models.js (wordpress core) i try to use the MediaFrame.EditAttachments view.

--code from media-models.js

```
if ( 'select' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.Select ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.Select( attributes );
} else if ( 'post' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.Post ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.Post( attributes );
} else if ( 'manage' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.Manage ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.Manage( attributes );
} else if ( 'image' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.ImageDetails ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.ImageDetails( attributes );
} else if ( 'audio' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.AudioDetails ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.AudioDetails( attributes );
} else if ( 'video' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.VideoDetails ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.VideoDetails( attributes );
} else if ( 'edit-attachments' === attributes.frame && MediaFrame.EditAttachments ) {
    frame = new MediaFrame.EditAttachments( attributes );
}
```

However i'm receiving this error

```
wp.media.view.MediaFrame.EditAttachments is not a constructor
```

Can you help me with a way to open the edit attachment in a modal window using  wp.media (or maybe another way)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a require call (eg `require("./views/frame/edit-attachments.js")`). That constructor is defined here:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6.1/src/wp-includes/js/media/views/frame/edit-attachments.js
Check were else it's used in the code and do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the logic of MediaFrame.EditAttachments isn't made to be used standalone - it requires the grid that opens it. You can however use the get_media_item( attachment_id ) method to receive the HTML of the form for modifying images: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_item/

Look also at my longer answer here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270008/wp-media-edit-attachment-screen/